# how to reset the datapicker date value to original value

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datepicker

I have a wpf application with datagrid and it has datapicker which has date value. If the user changes the date then some logic is run and a popup displayed as part of selectionChangedEvent hanlder code. If they choose 'No' on the popup then I Want to reset the date...Unable to figure this part

MyXaml

```
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Start Date">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <DatePicker Name="StartDate" SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate}" BorderThickness="0" SelectedDateChanged="StartDate_SelectedDateChanged">
                                        <DatePicker.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
                                                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </DatePicker.Resources>                                            
                                    </DatePicker>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Code

```
     Private Sub ValidateDateChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs)
        If MessageBoxResult.No = MessageBox.Show("Yes to Continue with the change",
                                                    vbApplicationModal + MsgBoxStyle.Information, MessageBoxButton.YesNo) Then
             how to reset the date value to the original value and stop event handler to not invoke again for this ovriden date change
             was trying this e.source.SelectedDate = CType(e.RemovedItems(0), Date)
        End If
     Sub
```

**UPDATE:** Problem is two additional events for the same datepicker are fired causing the popup to be displayed three times. This happens at the time of the load also

Comment: you can get new and old value from the event args of  `SelectedDateChanged` event.

Comment: Problem is event would fire again when the value is changed programmatically causing the popup to show up on reset

Comment: I understand your problem. What I might do in this case is maybe keep a flag to track how the value is changing. If you are resetting you can mark this flag as true otherwise false.
If I get a better approach, I'll suggest you later.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't check yesterday. If you are using a dependency property as a backing field for binding to datetime picker, I have one more suggestion for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Boolean` variable to temporarily suspend the event handler from actually doing something, e.g.:

```
Private _handleEvent As Boolean = True
Private Sub ValidateDateChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs)
    If _handleEvent And MessageBoxResult.No = MessageBox.Show("Yes to Continue with the change",
                                                   vbApplicationModal + MsgBoxStyle.Information, MessageBoxButton.YesNo) Then
        Dim dp As DatePicker = CType(sender, DatePicker)
        _handleEvent = False
        dp.SelectedDate = CType(e.RemovedItems(0), Date?)
        _handleEvent = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I had already tried this approach and it did not work.. Issue I am facing is there are two additional selection changed events are firing for the same datepicker causing the popup to be displayed two additional times. A total three popups

Comment: As much as I did not like it..I still had to use count variable to ignore the extra event fire..Not sure why it was firing two additional events. Issue is similar to this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8a1d9322-d837-4b86-bb4f-5444e5ddbee2/datepicker-selecteddatechanged-event-fire-twice?forum=csharpgeneral